# Proof for lineary independent of given set

Tags: vector-spaces

I have to test the set $\{f_i | i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ for lineary independence. $f_j\in (\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Q})$ is defined by 
$f (x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-n & n \geq i \\
0 &  n<i \\
\end{array}
\right. (n\in \mathbb{N})$

For lineary independence I have to determine, if $\sum_{i=0}^{j}{a_i f_i(n)}=0$  has the trivial solution only. However I'm not sure how I can test it, because I'm concerned about the case-switch. Can someone help me and explain me, how I can test this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, $f_0=f_1$. Other than that, they are linearly independent. Do you consider $0\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: no, $\mathbb{N}$ starts with 1 in my class.